# How to mock custom ILoggerManager to do UnitTest

Tags: c#, mocking

I declared a class `LogManager` and an **interface** `ILogManager`, and has a method `LoggerError`,  this method use `ILogger` (DI) to logerror and do other things.

There is a class `A` (DI ILogClass ) and declare a method  `funA()`， and `funA()` will use `_LogManager.LoggerError("test message")`.

- When do I unit test with mock ?
- How to `Verify` `_LogManager.LoggerError("test message")` ?

If I just use `ILogger` in class `A`, I can `Verify` with :

```
loggerMock.Verify(l => l.Log(LogLevel.Error,It.IsAny<EventId>(),
It.Is<object>(o => o.ToString().Contains("test message")),null,It.IsAny<Func<object, Exception, string>>()), Times.Once);
```

But not support with `ILogManager` mock.

```
public class LoggerManager<TCategoryName> : ILoggerManager<TCategoryName>
{
    private readonly ILogger<TCategoryName> _logger;
    public LoggerManager(ILogger<TCategoryName> logger)
    {
        this._logger = logger;
    }
    public void LogError(string message, LoggerErrorType type)
    {
     var errorLogger = NLog.LogManager.GetLogger(loggerName);
     errorLogger.Error(message);
    }
}

class A
{
....DI
     public void Test()
     {
         _loggerManager.LogError("test message")
     }
}


UT:
public void TestUT()
{
    var loggerMock = new Mock ILoggerManager A>>();
    var service = ServiceFactory.Create<A>(loggerMock);

    service.Test();
    //how to Verify logerror message?
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `LoggerManager<TCategoryName>` is just a wrapper over the `ILogger<TCategoryName>` and thus you can just mock `ILogger<TCategoryName>` and verify the same as you have already done and that should work just fine.

Though while making the actuall call to SUT you will have to dependency inject the `LoggerManager<TCategoryName>` accordingly

Comment: I tried, if  LoggerManager<TCategoryName> ：ILogger<TCategoryName>， I must have to implement three method for ILogger ?